# pandas dataframe to a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data, but I want the final output to remove the keys and just be a list of dictionaries.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5],'firstname':['John','Gerry','Sarah','Pierre','Angela'],
'lastname': ['Doe','Ronald','Lee','Sam','Perez']})

df = df.T
df = [df.to_dict()]

[{0: {'id': 1, 'firstname': 'John', 'lastname': 'Doe'},
  1: {'id': 2, 'firstname': 'Gerry', 'lastname': 'Ronald'},
  2: {'id': 3, 'firstname': 'Sarah', 'lastname': 'Lee'},
  3: {'id': 4, 'firstname': 'Pierre', 'lastname': 'Sam'},
  4: {'id': 5, 'firstname': 'Angela', 'lastname': 'Perez'}}]
```

Desired output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'firstname': 'John', 'lastname': 'Doe'},
 {'id': 2, 'firstname': 'Gerry', 'lastname': 'Ronald'},
 {'id': 3, 'firstname': 'Sarah', 'lastname': 'Lee'},
 {'id': 4, 'firstname': 'Pierre', 'lastname': 'Sam'},
 {'id': 5, 'firstname': 'Angela', 'lastname': 'Perez'}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `orient=records`:

```
result = df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{'id': 1, 'firstname': 'John', 'lastname': 'Doe'},
 {'id': 2, 'firstname': 'Gerry', 'lastname': 'Ronald'},
 {'id': 3, 'firstname': 'Sarah', 'lastname': 'Lee'},
 {'id': 4, 'firstname': 'Pierre', 'lastname': 'Sam'},
 {'id': 5, 'firstname': 'Angela', 'lastname': 'Perez'}]
```